# Related selectboxes using ajax and spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have problem with 2 dropdowns (second box options depends on first box currently selected option). What I have now is:
**controller**:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(ADMINISTRATION)
{...}
    @RequestMapping(value = USERS + STUDENT + "/reloadGroups/{schoolId}", method = GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<StudyGroup> reloadGroups(@PathVariable(value = "schoolId") final int schoolId) {
        return studyGroupService.getStudyGroupBySchool(schoolService.getSchool(schoolId));
    }
```

**html**:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(
                    function() {
                        var selectSchool = $("#school");
                        var selectGroup = $("#studyGroup");

                        selectSchool.change(function() {
                            var schoolId = $("#school option:selected").val();

                            $.get("/administration/users/student/reloadGroups/"
                                    + schoolId, function(data) {
                                selectGroup.empty();
                                console.log(data);
                                var group = JSON.parse(data);
                                for ( var option in data) {
                                    selectGroup.append($("<option/>", {
                                        text : group[option].name,
                                        key : group[option].id
                                    }));
                                }
                            })

                        })
                    });
</script>
    //and of course 2 select boxes with ids 'school' and 'studyGroup'
```

I get errors like:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/administration/users/student/reloadGroups/2"
```

but I don't know why, request mapping should be ok. When I type in browser for example `http://localhost:8080/drdiet-web/administration/users/student/reloadGroups/1` error changes to 500:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8080/drdiet-web/administration/users/student/reloadGroups/1"
```

What could be wrong? I'm totally new at Ajax.

**EDIT**

This 'worked' before, but not exactly, because I could only once change first dropdown value so it affected the second one available options:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var selectSchool = $("#school");
        var selectGroup = $("#studyGroup");


        selectSchool.change(function(){
                var schoolId = $("#school option:selected").val();

            $.ajax({
            url: config.baseUrl + '/administration/users/student/reloadGroups/' + schoolId,
            type: 'GET',
            data: schoolId,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: 'text',
            error : function() {
                alert("error");
                console.log("error");
            },
            success: function(data){
                selectGroup.empty();
                var aaa = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(data);
                alert("ok");
                for(var opt in aaa){
                    selectGroup.append($("<option/>", {
                        text: aaa[opt].name,
                        key: aaa[opt].id
                    }));
                console.log(aaa[opt]);
                }
            }
            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: I also tried this with $.ajax() method, but it didn't work

Comment: If you're getting a 500 internal server error when you access the controller's url directly then I'd start by looking at your server logs to see if an exception is thrown and fix this problem first..

Comment: In /usr/share/tomcat7/logs there are only lines like `[07/Mar/2013:10:09:24 +0100] "GET /administration/users/student/reloadGroups/3 HTTP/1.1" 200 12` and in /usr/share/tomcat7/log files are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, error 404 was quite obvious (`config.baseUrl`). Internal server error (code 500) was caused by different types of lists in controller. I just didn't spot it, thanks for all replies.